# Neo4j: Batching cypher transactions and using the results of one query in the next

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

Using the [REST API batched endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html) you can issue batched cypher transactions against a Neo4j database.

When using the REST endpoint you can use the [results of one query](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html#rest-api-refer-to-items-created-earlier-in-the-same-batch-job) in the next query. Is it possible to do the same thing when using cypher queries?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [transactional endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html) you can keep the transaction open over the wire and read and write data continuously and so use responses from previous queries as inputs/parameters into the next statement.

```
:POST /db/data/transaction {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(f:Person) WHERE n.name = {name} RETURN f.name as friends","parameters":{"name":"Aran"}}]}

-> returns friends -> ["John","Max","Fred"]

:POST /db/data/transaction/123 {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n:Person {name:{name}}) SET n.favorited = true","parameters":{"name":["John","Max","Fred"]}}]}

:POST /db/data/transaction/123/commit
```

Comment: It seems like OP wants something like the pipeline in MongoDB. Is there anything in the roadmap for Neo4j that will approximate that feature?

Comment: Looking more for a similar functionality to the batched end point that allows the id's of newly inserted nodes to be used in the next query. Doing research at the moment, don't mind looking at the transactional endpoint but like the batched one as it cuts down on the number of http requests.